# Connect Server to multiple Networks

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, windows, private-ip

I have a server that I'm trying to connect to multiple network ranges (172.x.xx, 10.x.x.x). I'm not really concerned with Domain issues I just want to be able to access my storage / management network and my public facing network from one spot.  Right now I have two nics and two adapters configured but I can only access objects on the 172 network.  Thanks

Edit

---

Here is the IP configuration, also the OS (2008r2) is on the 172 Domain.  When I get in the cmd I can ping the 172. network but not the 10. network (this is regardless of whether I'm on the domain or not).  Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: And what happens when you try to access other IP address?  What exactly does your configuration look like? What's your routing table look like?

Comment: @devicenull I added the IP configuration

Comment: Well, that's your problem.  IIRC Windows complains when you try to set two gateways at once.  Did you actually read the popup that appears when you try to save the network settings?  You need to change your routing table.  Right now, I'd expect you to be able to access all the IPs in the same subnet as you (10.0.0.0/24 and 172.20.40.0/24).  IPs outside of those subets would be a toss up, it depends on the routing table.

Comment: @devicenull Yeah I saw the popups Ive done this before and haven't had an issue.  I actually don't need the 10.0.0.254 gateway and I tried to leave it blank (which stops the popup) but that doesn't allow me to ping anything on the 10 network.

Comment: My guess is that you've got an incorrect subnet mask configured on the 10.0.0.x NIC. Are you sure it's supposed to be 255.255.255.0?

Comment: How exactly is that a bad mask? He should still be able to ping other 10.0.0.x addys

Comment: Define '10 network'.  In your initial question, you talked about 10.0.0.0/8.  In your network configuration, you show 10.0.0.0/24.  Without the gateway address, you should be able to access 10.0.0.1-10.0.0.255 using the subnet mask of 255.255.255.0.

Comment: @devicenull The 10. Network is the storage network it is a standard network nothing crazy.  I did notice now that I can ping 10.0.0.9 which is the Domain Controller on that newtwork however this is address I can ping.  Can't ping 10.0.0.2 or 10.0.0.3 which are the SAN addreses.

Comment: FYI, you can have multiple gateways set, the interface metric then decides which one is used.

Comment: Please add the output from the ping command and details of exactly what address you are pinging

Comment: There's nothing in your network configuration that would prevent what you're trying to do (access the 10.0.0.x devices). It must be an issue with firewalling (either on the local machine, remote device, or any passive firewalls inbetween), switching, or the remote device's configuration.

Comment: I'm with Chris on this one.  Assuming the rest of the network the 10.x nic is plugged into is correct, you should be able to hit devices on that network through that nic.  Start looking upstream from that nic.

Comment: Checking arp tables and listening the problematic interace with WinDump may help resolving this issue.

Comment: Defining 2 default gateways won't stop you accessing both networks. The default gateway is only used when trying to access foreign IP's that don't fit within either network/mask combination. If you define 2 gateways Windows will usually favour one of them (the first one defined from memory) and the other will be ignored.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right network and mask set up for the 10 network?  Have you given the server a valid IP?  Is the switch port on a VLAN?  Have you got the switch setup correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two DEFAULT gateways. A default gateway is the gateway that is used for all traffic that does not have a more specific route defined. You can see how having two of these wouldn't make sense.

You need to add a default gateway to one of the interfaces and create a static route bound to the other interface for the other network with `route.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Like SpacemanSpiff mentioned about multiple default gateways for the interface.
I had a similar problem which was resolved after adding the second default gateway on the interface.

Comment: You resolved your problem after **adding** a second default gateway? Really?

Answer (score 0):

First, use the right terms. You are talking about the 10.0.0.x network with a netmask of /24.

A 10-network would be 10.x.y.z with a netmask of /8.

Now if you do not need a gateway for this network - do not define one. You only need a (default) routing-entry if you want to leave that network with an address within that network.

I suspect there is something wrong on your route back from the SAN-devices (.2 and .3) you can not ping. So take a closer look at their configuration.